# Argument of type '{ useNewUrlParser: boolean; useUnifiedTopology: boolean}' is not assignable to parameter of type'

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to connect my Node.js server to Atlas mongo database. I am using mongoose for this.

```
await mongoose
      .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI!, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        poolSize: parseInt(process.env.POOL_SIZE!),
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(
          'Connected to Distribution API Database - Initial Connection'
        );
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(
          `Initial Distribution API Database connection error occured -`,
          err
        );
      });
```

My dependencies related to this in the package.json file is as below

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/mongoose": "5.7.29",
    "mongoose": "5.9.21",
    "typescript": "3.9.5"
  },
```

This was working earlier without any issues (I did not update @types/mongoose or mongoose versions at all) and suddenly now I am getting the below error

```
Compilation error in /app/src/index.ts
Using ts-node version 8.10.2, typescript version 3.9.5
[ERROR] 16:25:18 ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript: src/index.ts(59,11): error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(uris: string, callback: (err: MongoError) => void): Promise<typeof import("mongoose")>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ useNewUrlParser: boolean; useUnifiedTopology: boolean; useCreateIndex: boolean; useFindAndModify: boolean; poolSize: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: MongoError) => void'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'useNewUrlParser' does not exist in type '(err: MongoError) => void'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(uris: string, options?: ConnectionOptions | undefined): Promise<typeof import("mongoose")>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ useNewUrlParser: true; useUnifiedTopology: true; useCreateIndex: true; useFindAndModify: false; poolSize: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConnectionOptions'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'poolSize' does not exist in type 'ConnectionOptions'
```

Can someone help me on this?? Really appreciate any thoughts on this.

Thanks

Comment: Mongoose has its own types, `@types/mongoose` is deprecated: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mongoose.

Comment: @jonrsharpe But still the old code should work right?? Since I have not updated to the latest at all. I am confused why this issue occurs though

Comment: I suspect it's because you previously had options as a variable, and now have an object literal. Variables don't get checked for excess properties, while object literals do: [playground](https://tsplay.dev/w2K2VN)

Comment: But this was working fine. I never changed this code. It was always like shown above. I can imagine this to happen if i updated typescript package or the @types/mongoose which i did not

Comment: this is not part of the new api driver client options. fyi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated the mongoose to the latest. Removed type/mongoose solved the issue.

Answer (score 27):

You can change your connect function to

```
await mongoose
      .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI!, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        poolSize: parseInt(process.env.POOL_SIZE!),
      } as ConnectOptions)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(
          'Connected to Distribution API Database - Initial Connection'
        );
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(
          `Initial Distribution API Database connection error occured -`,
          err
        );
      });
```

You can use this to import ConnectOptions

```
import mongoose, { ConnectOptions } from "mongoose";
```

Comment: This should've been the accepted answer. Casting the correct type solved it.

Answer (score 8):

npm package **"@types/mongoose"** has been deprecated as the latest version of Mongoose publishes its own types.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mongoose

Therefore, the latest version of mongoose (6.0.3) doesn't provide connect options for useNewUrlParser, useCreateIndex, useUnifiedTopology, and useFindAndModify.

To solve this, downgrade mongoose to older version like **5.13.8**, then it should be working fine without any issues. :)

Answer (score 8):

For those who are using the latest version as of this post, `useNewUrlParser`, `useUnifiedTopology`, `useFindAndModify`, and `useCreateIndex` **are no longer supported options**.

See updated example code below:

```js
const URI = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test';

await mongoose.connect(URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true, // <-- no longer necessary
  useUnifiedTopology: true // <-- no longer necessary
});
```

Since the release of v6, Mongoose always behaves as if `useNewUrlParser`, `useUnifiedTopology`, and `useCreateIndex` are `true`, and `useFindAndModify` is `false`.

Comment: +1
It's well stated in the official Mongoose doc below https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#no-more-deprecation-warning-options

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose Updated so, you need to change **useCreateIndex:true** to **autoIndex:true** only and will work:

```
import mongoose, {ConnectOptions} from "mongoose";

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.URLDBMONGO || "http://localhost:8000", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    autoIndex: true,
  } as ConnectOptions)
  .then((db) => {
    console.log("Database Connected Successfuly.");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Error Connectiong to the Database");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using the latest version as of this post, useNewUrlParser, useUnifiedTopology, useFindAndModify, and useCreateIndex are no longer supported options.

See updated example code below:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const MONGODB_URL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test'

if (!MONGODB_URL) {
    throw new Error(
        "Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable inside .env.local"
    )
}


let cached = global.mongoose;



if (!cached) {
    cached = global.mongoose = {con: null, promise: null}
}

const dbConnect = async () => {
    if (cached.conn) {
        return cached.conn;
    }


// If a connection does not exist, we check if a promise is already in progress. If a promise is already in progress, we wait for it to resolve to get the connection
    if (!cached.promise) {
        const opts = {
            useNewUrlParser: true, // <-- no longer necessary
            useUnifiedTopology: true, // <-- no longer necessary
            useCreateIndex: true, // <-- no longer necessary
            useFindAndModify: false, // <-- no longer necessary
            bufferCommands : false
        };

        cached.promise = mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URL, opts).then((mongoose) => {
            return mongoose
        })
    }

    try {
        cached.conn = await cached.promise;
    } catch (e) {
        cached.promise = null;
        throw e;
    }

    return cached.conn;
}

export default dbConnect;
```

Since the release of v6, Mongoose always behaves as if useNewUrlParser, useUnifiedTopology, and useCreateIndex are true, and useFindAndModify is false.