# Argument of type ‘{ useNewUrlParser: boolean; useUnifiedTopology: boolean}’ is not assignable to parameter of type’

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

Hello I am using `"mongodb": "^4.7.0"` (I am using mongodb atlas)

Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
"@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
"@types/express": "^4.17.13",
"@types/morgan": "^1.9.3",
"@types/node": "^17.0.40",
"@types/nodemon": "^1.19.1",
"axios": "^0.27.2",
"dotenv": "^16.0.1",
"express": "^4.18.1",
"mongodb": "^4.7.0",
"morgan": "^1.10.0",
"nodemon": "^2.0.16",
"ts-node": "^10.8.1",
"typescript": "^4.7.3"
```

}

This is the line of code that has an error:

```
const CLIENT: MongoClient = new MongoClient(MONGO_URI, OPTIONS);
```

This is the OPTIONS constant:

```
const OPTIONS = {

  useNewUrlParser: true,

  useUnifiedTopology: true,

};
```

This is the error:

**Type '{ useNewUrlParser: boolean; useUnifiedTopology: boolean; }' has no properties in common with type 'MongoClientOptions'.**

I’ve looked at these answers:

https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/argument-of-type-usenewurlparser-boolean-useunifiedtopology-boolean-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type/119731/5

[Argument of type '{ useNewUrlParser: boolean; useUnifiedTopology: boolean}' is not assignable to parameter of type'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68806347/argument-of-type-usenewurlparser-boolean-useunifiedtopology-boolean-is-n)

Note: I am not using mongoose like the others in the answers nor am I using poolSize.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You can check the full list of available options for `MongoClient` at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/connection/connection-options/

Comment: What I find odd, is that I've been using these settings on a few projects that are just written in JS. I do not find useNewUrlParser or useUnifiedTopology in the list of version 4.3 - 4.5.

Comment: I understand that, but I've been using these options specs without mongoose on older projects.